# function to duplicate images for thumbnail?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, duplicates, compression

I'm making a photo gallery app.

I'm compressing the images

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.5)
```

and then want to create a duplicate (for thumbnails) that I'll compress even further

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.2)
```

I'm a little stuck on the middle step of how to create a duplicate, anyone know if there is a function for this?

Comment: what to you want to do ...explain more ...

Comment: take a look at: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-save-a-uiimage-to-a-file-using-uiimagepngrepresentation

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can convert `NSData` to `UIImage`.

Swift3:

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbImage,0.5)
let thumbImage = UIImage(data:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(data: imageData),0.2))
```

Objective C:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.5)
UIImage *thumb = [UIImage imageWithData: UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithData: imageData],0.5)];
```